# Supplying tsvector for full search in postgres as part of FROM

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.4

I have a text search query that looks like this

```
with query as (select to_tsquery('sometext'))
select
    t1.id
from 
    table1 as t1,
    to_tsvector(t1.f1) as vector
where
    (select * from query) @@ vector
```

This works as expected. But when I try to add more fields to the vector like this

```
with query as (select to_tsquery('sometext'))
select
    t1.id
from 
    table1 as t1,
    to_tsvector(t1.f1) || to_tsvector(t1.f2) as vector
where
    (select * from query) @@ vector
```

I get a syntax error near ||. What am I doing wrong here?

My database is PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FROM list is allowed to have a function call as if it were a table, but not an operator expression.  You can translate it to the equivalent function call:

```
with query as (select to_tsquery('sometext'))
select
    t1.id
from 
    table1 as t1,
    tsvector_concat(to_tsvector(t1.f1), to_tsvector(t1.f2)) as vector
where
    (select * from query) @@ vector
```